# Upgrading router in 2024

Tags: wifi, networking, router

I'm a little out of the loop on the state of WiFi these days so looking for a bit of advice about a possible upgrade.

We have BT cable in the house currently (can't switch providers at present), and it gives us decent speeds - I think we're on their 100gb package.

I'm of the opinion that routers supplied by ISPs are pretty crap, so have been considering an upgrade for a while.

Only 2 of us in the house, but we have multiple PCs, laptops, phones, tablets, games consoles, TVs etc. I also have a decent amount of IoT type stuff like smart lights, Google Homes, my home theatre. There are probably getting on for 30 devices connected.

As you'd expect, we will do a lot of gaming, a decent amount of 4k streaming and obviously want a stable network for all these devices.

Based on a quick refresher, it looks like WiFi 6 is the new thing - but does anyone have recommendations for what to be on the lookout for spec wise, or specific product recommendations?

Budget is probably up to about £200. My property isn't huge and is a new build so not sure if there is any value to Mesh.

Comment: How many square feet are you trying to cover? A single AP may be enough, depending on how large your area is and how many walls and such you've got in the way. By the way: if you want a deep dive into the various versions of Wi-Fi and what various specs mean, [this guide](https://www.wiisfi.com) is fantastic (if pretty long.)